# Flashing a new image on a beaglebone black rev c via. USB

Tags: beagleboneblack

How can we flash a new image on a beaglebone black rev c via. USB without using sdcard ?

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/ungureanuvladvictor/BBBlfs.

This is a tool designed to utilize the USB booting mode of the AM335x series of processors.